# Running Line of code twice causes activeX error 0x8000ffff

Tags: vb.net, variables, crash, activex

Following code causes an ActiveX error 0x8000ffff if executed twice.

It all boils down to this two lines, as the rest of the code runs smoothly.
In particular, if I run the line of code only once, it works great. If I run the line of code twice I get the error. Note that the line is only reading the variable, so I do not understand why it would not be readable the second time. If s_Var changes, then it works, essentially i can read every column once.

This works:

```
         obj_Dlr = GetDataLoggerRecipe(s_Dlr)
         If Not s_Var = "" Then

            Debug.Print obj_Dlr.GetColumn(s_Var).Name

         End If
```

This not:

```
         obj_Dlr = GetDataLoggerRecipe(s_Dlr)
         If Not s_Var = "" Then

            Debug.Print obj_Dlr.GetColumn(s_Var).Name
            Debug.Print obj_Dlr.GetColumn(s_Var).Name

         End If
```

Also reassigning the variable does not work..

```
         obj_Dlr = GetDataLoggerRecipe(s_Dlr)
         If Not s_Var = "" Then

            Debug.Print obj_Dlr.GetColumn(s_Var).Name

         End If

         obj_Dlr = GetDataLoggerRecipe(s_Dlr)
         If Not s_Var = "" Then

            Debug.Print obj_Dlr.GetColumn(s_Var).Name

         End If
```

I'm interested in understanding what is going on, as it helps me to solve anotehr problem.

Thanks

Comment: What if you set a variable to the column name and then print the variable twice? It should still work right?

Comment: yes, it works, but this is just a short sample to explain  the problem. In reality, i am not calling the debug twice.. i am calling the entire script twice. but the result is the same.

Comment: I understand. I was just curious to see if maybe it was the printing. But it is definitely calling. Do you have the code for that object (`obj_Dlr`)?

Comment: nope... all I have is the decalration `Dim obj_Dlr As DLRCmdTarget`. its part of movicon's Scripting.

Comment: Ah. Sorry I'm not much help then. I think it must be on their side. Could it be intended that you can only read each one once? It doesn't seem to make much sense.